# python 3 tweepy csv encode

Tags: python, csv, twitter, encode

Please help to resolve the error. I am trying to get tweets from twitter and write it into a csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv
import codecs



#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
--
--
--
--


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print ('getting tweets before %s' % (oldest))

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with codecs.open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:

        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([bytes(id,'utf-8'),bytes(created_at,'utf-8'),bytes(text,'utf-8')])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("gokul7071")
```

Error

getting tweets before 529619651269894144
...3 tweets downloaded so far

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PraveenMS\Desktop\tweepy-3.3.0\examples\importtweepy.py", line 67, in <module>
    get_all_tweets("gokul7071")
  File "C:\Users\PraveenMS\Desktop\tweepy-3.3.0\examples\importtweepy.py", line 59, in get_all_tweets
    writer.writerow([bytes(id,'utf-8'),bytes(created_at,'utf-8'),bytes(text,'utf-8')])
TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument
```

getting tweets before 529619651269894144
    ...3 tweets downloaded so far

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PraveenMS\Desktop\tweepy-3.3.0\examples\importtweepy.py", line 67, in <module>
    get_all_tweets("gokul7071")
  File "C:\Users\PraveenMS\Desktop\tweepy-3.3.0\examples\importtweepy.py", line 59, in get_all_tweets
    writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: #write the csv  
        with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                a_new = [tuple(map(str, i)) for i in outtweets]
                writer.writerow(str.encode("id"),str.encode("created_at"),str.encode("text"),str.encode("media_url")
                writer.writerows(str.encode(a_new))

Comment: Tried the above code as well. I face error while converting str list to bytes using encode function.

Answer (score 0):

Writing data with writerow is always difficult you need to follow various encoding characterstics there are other simplier ways to collects tweets and store it in a csv file...if you can tell what exact contents you want to store..that it might be easier to give an appropriate solution..

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

ckey = '######'
csecret = '#####'
atoken = '####'
asecret = '#####'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
      try:
          print data
          saveFile = open('Filename.csv','a')
          saveFile.write(data)
          saveFile.write('\n')
          saveFile.close()
          return True
      except BaseException, e:
          print 'failed ondata',str(e)
          time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Obama"],languages='en')
```

This is sample example of how to stream tweets about the term "Obama"...and it create a file named Filename.csv...I hope this helps...you question is not descriptive about what you want

Comment: I would like to get all tweets of a user and save in a csv. Kindly help me to achieve it

Comment: ok...this works fine for me it collects all tweets and store it in csv check this out...https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496#file-tweet_dumper-py-L36

Comment: Can you use the above code to get all tweets of  '@xxxxx' ?

Comment: it gives you the most recent tweets..i got 3240 tweets of a particular user